# Doctrine ORM with Mustache

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mustache

I'm trying to output the result from a doctrine query to a mustache template.
So far the only way I can get it to work is if I make the attributes public.
But this doesn't seem right.
Is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: Wild guess because you didn't provide enough information and context for a full answer: are you using `{{ thing.foo }}` when your accessor method is named `getFoo`? Try `{{ thing.getFoo }}`.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't think to do that. That works!  I will include example code in the future.  I was using {{#program}}
         {{id}}
{{/program}}